# Focus on + (verb+ing) or (to+verb)

Tags: grammar, american-english, speech

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

"In spite of the toughness, **what I focus on is 'to carry' on and 'fight' until I win**."

Which one is correct :
What I focus on is to carry on ...
My focus is to carry on ...